# How to signal a change in the post?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, updating

I was wondering how to reproduce the feature which is visible even on the StackOverflow page: when a user edits an answer for other users appear: "an edit has been made to this post; click to load". This is the functionality I am referring to:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox

Basically, I have a function which takes some time to return the value, and once it happens I would like to update UI.

Comment: Did you read the post you linked?

Answer (score 1):

As they say in the post you are linking, only browsers that supports web sockets can use this feature. Read up on those, they are not too hard to use. It basically it enables the server to "push" data to the client. Be aware though that most servers doesn't support web sockets without extensions at the moment. Neither does all browsers.

Another solution would be to utilize an AJAX request, with `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, checking to see if new posts have arrived each i.e. 10th second. This will generate more http requests, but it should be more compatible. Also, it isn't true real time.